# How assign rev command to a variable in shell

Tags: shell, variables, output, assign

I wanted to direct the output of rev command to a variable, I tried different methods and didn't work.

```
 read -p "Enter the number: " n   
 echo $n | rev
 echo "new n is: $p"
```

I want to assign the output of line 2 to p. How?

Thank you,

Comment: To store the output of a command in a variable, use the `varname=$(command)` syntax, in this example `p=$(echo $n | rev)`

Comment: Absolutely correct! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the output of a command in a variable use a `$(...)` command substitution:

```
p=$(echo $n | rev)
```

For further reference, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)